# Copy first letter uppercase text and first letter lowercase text to two columns

Tags: excel, vba

I need to read a txt file and copy elements with first letter uppercase to one column and ones with lowercase to other column.

```
Public Sub uzd3()

Dim fd As FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
Dim filename As String

If fd.Show = -1 Then
    filename = fd.SelectedItems(1)
    MsgBox ("The path is: " & filename)
    Open "C:\Users\KlaavsZK\Desktop\uzd3.txt" For Input As #1
Else
    MsgBox ("No file selected")
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim txt As String
Dim i As Integer

i = 0
Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, txt
    Cells(1, 1) = "Lielais sakuma burts"
    Cells(1, 2) = "mazais sakuma  burts"
    If Left(Cells(2, 1).Offset(i, 0), 1) = LCase(Left(Cells(2, 1).Offset(i, 0), 1)) Then
        Cells(2, 1).Offset(i, 0) = txt
    ElseIf Left(Cells(2, 2).Offset(i, 0), 1) = UCase(Left(Cells(2, 2).Offset(i, 0), 1)) Then
        Cells(2, 2).Offset(i, 0) = txt
        i = i + 1
    End If
Loop
Close #1

End Sub
```

It copies elements to columns but randomly not by uppercase and lowercase.

Comment: Suggest you add an example of the input data, the desired output and the actual output to make it clearer as to what the issue is.  That will make the problem clearer and easier to help you with

Answer (score 0):

i believe that you problem is in this comparations

```
 Left(Cells(2, 1).Offset(i, 0), 1) = LCase(Left(Cells(2, 1).Offset(i, 0), 1))   
 Left(Cells(2, 2).Offset(i, 0), 1) = UCase(Left(Cells(2, 2).Offset(i, 0), 1))
```

you are checking the value of the cell but not the value you are reading from text file

try this

```
Public Sub uzd3()

Dim fd As FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
Dim filename As String

If fd.Show = -1 Then
    'filename = fd.SelectedItems(1)
    'MsgBox ("The path is: " & filename)
   Open "C:\Users\KlaavsZK\Desktop\uzd3.txt" For Input As #1
Else
    MsgBox ("No file selected")
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim txt As String
Dim i As Integer

Cells(1, 1) = "Lielais sakuma burts"
Cells(1, 2) = "mazais sakuma  burts"

    i = 0
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, txt

        If Left(txt, 1) = LCase(Left(txt, 1)) Then
            Cells(2, 1).Offset(i, 0) = txt
        ElseIf Left(txt, 1) = UCase(Left(txt, 1)) Then
           Cells(2, 2).Offset(i, 0) = txt

        End If
                    i = i + 1
    Loop
Close #1

End Sub
```

Good Luck